# Strategy to study random effects with package lme4 or lmertest?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a training dataset (95 840 rows) with:

```
str(train)
$ NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON       : Factor w/ 9 levels "8647","8666",..: 3 4 5 8 9 1 2 3 4 6 ...
$ TEMPERATURE_AIR            : num  6.29 6.13 6 7.05 8.16 ...
$ MonthNumber                : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
$ HOURS                      : Factor w/ 24 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 ...
$ TEMPERATURE_COUPON         : num  5.1 6.6 4.5 5.4 4.7 ...
```

I'm trying to predict temperature TEMPERATURE_COUPON gotten from 9 various sites (#id=NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) with 1 continuous variable TEMPERATURE_AIR            and 2 categorials variables MonthNumber and HOURS.

My best model is with a Linear Model with interactions:

```
train=read.csv2("train.csv") 
train[,'MonthNumber'] = factor(train[,'MonthNumber'])
train[,'HOURS'] = factor(train[,'HOURS'])
train[,'NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON'] = factor(train[,'NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON'])

data <- train[which(train$NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON != 8668),]
reg_full_interactions_temperature_air_mois_heure = lm(TEMPERATURE_COUPON ~ TEMPERATURE_AIR * MonthNumber * HOURS, data=data) 
r2 = summary(reg_full_interactions_temperature_air_mois_heure)$r.squared 
print(paste("R2= ", r2 , " BIC=",bic))
"R2=  0.922056526653646  BIC= 443093.296374013"
```

So now I want to improve my best model by studying random effects of NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON.

First is it a good idea to start from the fixed effects with the previous interaction?

But I have no idea to study which randoms effects: for the intercept, for each individual covariable TEMPERATURE_AIR, MonthNumber and HOURS?

```
library(lmerTest)
library(MuMIn)

data_train <- train[which(train$NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON != 8668),]
reg_ml1 = lmerTest::lmer(TEMPERATURE_COUPON ~ TEMPERATURE_AIR * MonthNumber * HOURS + (1 | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON), data = data_train)
    
# To get R2 with lmertest()
MuMIn::r.squaredGLMM(reg_ml1)
```

What's the strategy?

Comment: You should tell us more on what is your data and what question you are trying to answer with it.

Comment: I filled the answer. It's more clearly now I think. Thanks.